# Managing multiple types of devices

Tags: ios, android, apple, microsoft

I'm not really a sysadmin, it's more like I got asked to manage a few devices the organisation has.

We got surface gos, ipads, Andriod tablets and VR headsets. About 10 to 15 sets of each type and they are not assigned for any specific user (they are mostly for event purposes). I have been told to use a MDM or some kind of device management solution but I do have a few questions before I go requesting one.

- Can I use one account to manage each type of device? (i.e. one Ms
  account for all the surfaces, one apple id for all the iOS devices,
  one google account for all the Androids etc, and one meta account for the
  quest).
- Could I still run the same apps simultaneously on multiple devices
  with the above setup? Think the only one I can't do that is for VR
  apps from the Oculus store? But how about the others?
- If I were to use an MDM, can I do that all on one account or do I need individual accounts for each device?

Comment: Without being more specific about the actual solution than *"a MDM or some kind of device management solution"*  it is difficult to provide anything else than *"it depends"*  (on the device, the firmware version, on which MDM product is chosen, etc. etc.)  and similar generic answers that can also be found in for example the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_device_management article...  -_-_ And it could be that simply wiping the devices before each event and locking them in their native kiosk/restricted mode is already enough and much cheaper overall than a full MDM solution....

Comment: Cross-posted from Super User: https://superuser.com/q/1740115/356789